# mySQL table structure with Array type

Tags: mysql, arrays

i want match_history to be array of foregin keys to connect between a user and his matches. mySQL dont support array types so i thought to do a string looks like array but i dont know how to connect his ids with the matches with foregin keys.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    encrypted_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    points INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    **match_history TEXT DEFAULT '[]',**
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE matches (
    match_id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    player1_id INT NOT NULL,
    player2_id INT NOT NULL,
    game_status INT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (match_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (player1_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (player2_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```